# How to check if email exists in xml file

Tags: php, html, xml

I want the system to check whether the email exists in the xml file when a new registration occurs, how can I do that? I got the basic idea of comparing all the email nodes but still cant get it to work after several hours. Thanks for the help

register.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>ShipOnline System Registration Page</h1>
<form id="regform" method="post" action="register.php">
<fieldset id="person"> 
<legend>Your details:</legend>
<p><label for="fname">First Name:</label><input type="text" name="fname"/></p>
<p><label for="lname">Last Name:</label><input type="text" name="lname"/></p>
<p><label for="password">Password:</label><input type="password" name="password"/></p>
<p><label for="cpassword">Confirm Password:</label><input type="password" name="cpassword"/></p>            
<p><label for="email">Email:</label><input type="email" id="email" name="email"/></p>
<p><label for="phone">Phone:</label><input type="text" name="phone"/></p>
<input type="submit" value="Register"/>
</fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

relevant parts of register.php

```
<?php
$email = @trim($_POST["email"]);
if ($password != $cpassword)
{
    echo 'Password does not match';
}
@override
else if ($email /*exists*/)
{
    echo 'Email exists';
}
?>
```

customer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<customer>
<user>
    <id>0</id>
    <fname>John</fname>
    <lname>Smith</lname>
    <email>jsmith@gmail.com</email>
    <password>jsmith</password>
    <phone>0412345677</phone>
</user>
<user>
    <id>1</id>
    <fname>Arthur</fname>
    <lname>Luo</lname>
    <email>aluo@gmail.com</email>
    <password>aluo</password>
    <phone>0412345678</phone>
</user>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to do a simple search of the contents of your XML file. This is fine if you are confident that there are not other `<email>` tags containing the email address in some other context. For example:

```
# slurp the XML file into a variable
$xml = file_get_contents('customer.xml');
# search for the email address within the tags
if (strpos($xml, "<email>$email</email>") !== false)) {
    # you've found it!
}
```

You can also use DOMDocument and DOMXPath to parse the XML and search for the email address. To be honest, this seems like overkill given the simplicity of the XML file you've posted.

Comment: mind the XML injection.

Comment: @hakre might be more useful to give the OP links/advice about sanitising input.

Comment: well actually the question is asked wrong IMHO: Form + X + ... . OP should first ask on how to search XML for example. It's not of interest from a programming point of view where the search value comes from or if it is about email or bubble-gum-remove-machine-model-numbers. however with the way you suggest to search the XML it's not only that the XML needs to match requirements (e.g. no comments inside the email and/or entities like `&gt;`) but also about the input given. However the quick acceptance shows, that OP is less interested in solutions but more in collecting problems. better CV such

Comment: @hakre SO is, by its nature, mostly about people solving small problems and potentially creating larger problems for themselves because they lack experience--they don't know the "right" questions to ask. Often people just want a quick fix for their current issue and aren't interested in exploring further (or, say, reading comments that explain what the code is doing). That is the nature of the beast that is SO, unfortunately. btw, the site hosting your print_r parser is down. `:\`

Comment: yeah especially as such questions are already answered. that's why it's often better to point to the existing resources. that's what SO is for. once you find that out, it's more a problem of placing bad answers ^^ :)